# Web.Config varios dominios

Tags: rotas, web.config

Tenho uma hospedagem com vários domínios, cada site tem o seu sistema de rotas. Na hospedagem (httdocs) tem meu site principal onde configurei a rota do pelo web.config, até ai esta tudo funcionando normalmente. No entanto quando tento configurar a rota para outro site que está em outra pasta dentro da hospedagem não funciona.
Tenho que ter dois web.config? Um para cada site? Por que fiz isso é não funcionou.

Comment: Qual a linguagem e qual framework você está utilizando? Adicione essas duas informações na sua pergunta e nas tags.

Comment: Estou utilizando php com smarty template